# Homebrewed http start fails on macOS Big Sur

Tags: php, apache-2.4, mac-osx, httpd, brew

I had installed Apache 2.4.46 on macOS Big Sur via Homebrew.
It had worked fine until I did `brew update` and `brew upgrade`. At this time, PHP was upgraded from 7.4 to 8.0, so I modified httpd.conf as following.

```
#LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
#<IfModule php7_module>
#  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
#</IfModule>
#Updated to PHP 8.0.0.1
LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

After that, I modified `/usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php.ini` as the same as `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini`.

But `brew services start htppd` satys `==> Successfully started` httpd `(label: homebrew.mxcl.httpd)`, but `brew services list` shows `httpd error MyUserName /Users/MyUserName/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist`.

So I stopped httpd service on brew and started as follows.

```
$ apachectl start
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

So, I can't continue to investigate furthermore.

Help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you follow the instructions here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64912014/mac-os-big-sur-homebrew-apache-48address-already-in-use-ah00072-make-sock

Hopefully you or someone else might find it useful

Comment: Mr. Leye Odumuyiwa,
Thank you for your answer that includes a link to the topic that many people facing the same issue.
I sincerely appreciate it.
And I'd like to close this topic and try the ways that others succeeded on the topic you kindly shared with me.
It is also to unify the knowledge of the same issue.
Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome @MasaruKitajima